# How do I configure crafter profile client and crafter profile admin console with non-default crafter profile URL?

Tags: crafter-cms

The default configuration of crafter profile is http://localhost:8080/crafter-profile for Crafter Profile Client and Crafter Profile Admin Console. I have installed Crafter Profile on port 7070 and updated the following property in the extension folder:

/shared/classes/crafter/engine/extension/server-config.properties

crafter.profile.rest.client.url.base=http://localhost:7070/crafter-profile

But both instances are still looking for crafter-profile at port 8080.

`[WARN] 2017-06-07 13:16:23,158 [ajp-nio-7009-exec-71] [rest.RestTemplate] | GET request for "http://localhost:8080/crafter-profile/api/1/profile/by_ticket.json?accessTokenId=b4d44030-d0af-11e3-9c1a-0800200c`

`2017-06-07_13:17:11.085 [http-nio-7070-exec-62] WARN  o.c.commons.rest.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8080/crafter-profile/api/1/tenant/all.json?accessTokenId=e8f5170c-877b-416f-b70f-4b09772f8e2d" resulted in 404 (); invoking error handler`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Crafter-Profile-Admin console that property (`crafter.profile.rest.client.url.base`) should be in this file 
`crafter/profile/management/extension/server-config.properties` under tomcat shared folder.

When using the crafter-profile-client in spring context you should make sure that your spring context read a property file which and override of the key